# Counting elements in array column with map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that contains only one column with arrays

```scala
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  (Array("a", "b", "c")),
  (Array("d", "e"))
).toDF("value")
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

When I count the number of elements in each array using a column expression, I get the expected result:

```
df.select(size($"value")).show
```

prints

```
+-----------+
|size(value)|
+-----------+
|          3|
|          2|
+-----------+
```

When I try to map each row to its size, I only get a `1` in each row:

```
df.map(_.size).show
```

prints

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    1|
+-----+
```

Why does the second version only print `1` for each array instead of the array's size?

Comment: Because you are asking for the size of the **row** which is 1. If you want to use a `map` function, the best would be to use a type **Dataset**, try `df.as[Array[Int]].map(_.size).show()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size` on a `Row` gives the number of columns/fields, the doc says:

> Number of elements in the Row

which is 1 in your case.

What you can do instead is :

```
df.map(_.getSeq(0).size)
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    2|
+-----+
```